# How to use pycharm to debug cython line by line(break point) and cython assignment issue?

Tags: pycharm, cython

I found that PyCharm seems cannot debug the cython compiled code, I have read the official document of PyCharm , but this part didn't write clear.
Help Me please, I recently found a weird cython problem:

```
cdef class CRF_CFunction:
     cdef public int num_feature
     def __init__(self, object crf_pact_structure, int node_in_size):
           self.num_feature = crf_pact_structure.num_feature
           assert self.num_feature == crf_pact_structure.num_feature
```

but this assert will error , the `crf_pact_structure.num_feature = 164880` but the `self.num_feature = 33808`

Comment: By the way, I use windows and mingw to compile cython generated C code

Comment: You have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888501/debug-cython-code-pyx-when-using-the-python-debugger-pdb-best-practice and the documentation it links to?

Comment: I know there is command line way of debug. but I want to debug it in PyCharm, is it possible? I always use IDE

Comment: Probably not, but I don't know for sure

Comment: have you encounter my weried issue before？